# How to delete photos only from one device?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, iphone

As I have limited storage on my iPhone, can I delete photos from my iPhone and they will still remain on the iCloud? Or can they be accessed on my iPad which has more storage?

I think when I have deleted a picture on any device, they delete from the iPad as well (presumably through the iCloud).

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in [Apple's support article](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204570), you can disable iCloud Photo Library on your iOS device by tapping Settings > iCloud, and turning off "Photos".

Your photos will still remain in iCloud Photo Library but will be removed from your device.

Answer (score 2):

**You start your question by saying you have limited storage so I have taken the liberty of proposing a solution that doesn't delete, but instead stores smaller versions of your photos.**

Look at this [Apple doc iCloud Photo Library FAQ,](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) if the goal is simply to save space there are approaches that will help you in the

Quoting rather liberally from that article just in case Apple changes it when iOS 10 comes out:

**Can I use iCloud Photo Library to save space on my device?**

> iCloud Photo Library automatically keeps all your photos and videos in
>   the original, high-resolution version. Follow these steps to choose
>   how you store your photos and videos on your device:
>
> On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, tap Settings > iCloud > Photos or
>   Settings > Photos & Camera, then select a storage setting. On your
>   Mac, click Photos > Preferences > iCloud, then select a storage
>   setting.
>
> If you turn on Optimize [device] Storage, iCloud Photo Library will
>   automatically manage the size of your library on your device, so you
>   can make the most of your device's storage and access more photos than
>   ever. All of your original, full-resolution photos and videos are
>   stored in iCloud while device-size versions are kept on your device.
>   You can download the original photos and videos over Wi-Fi or cellular
>   when you need them.

I worked the phones for Applecare during the iOS 6, 7 and 8 releases. We were mushrooms, we were kept in the dark until a day or two before the release, then all this new training would hit. I am not sure who is more frustrated by Apple's constant changes in Photo Stream / iCloud Drive / iCloud Photo library, the employees or the customers! I hope Apple can settle into something their users can understand for the long term. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to store your photos long-term is your computer.

Cloud storage can be capricious, it's not worth the risk.

iPhoto or Image Capture on Mac, Photo Gallery [part of MS Essentials] on Windows, would be the safest.

Comment: I' like to comment on "The best place to store your photos long-term is your computer." although I guess _context_ is everything.  For long-term storage of photos I'd say on verified high-quality optical media stored in an appropriate fire-proof safe at home and or in the office or in one's bank safety deposit box.  Preferably no less then two copies, one each stored in separate locations as a redundant backup.  Then use your computer simply for what I'd call long-term easy access. If something happens to the computer the photos can be restored from optical media as needed.

Comment: I was assuming the computer would already have a competent backup strategy, of course. As the adage goes, "Any data stored in less than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary."

Comment: That's why I said "I guess _context_ is everything". :)  I certainly agree with the _less then three_ concept and why I have Time Machine to a RAID and then burn the most important data to verified high-quality optical media stored in fire-proof safe at home and have other copies in another separate physical location. :)

Comment: I have Time Machine for the Mac, Acronis for the PCs to an in-house server, plus Backblaze for off-site. Belt & braces ;) …oh, & iCloud, of course